# how to position matplotlib figures relative to screen dimensions

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to have a `matplotlib` figure with a given aspect ratio at maximum possible size of a given display.

So if it is a *wide* figure, it should use the *full width* of my screen (and the height is then given by the aspect ratio) **or** if it is a *very high* (portrait format) figure, it should use the *full height* of the screen, and the width is defined by the aspect ratio.

A possible alternative would be a figure that uses the full screen size **without** being in the full-screen mode (i.e. without using `plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()`).

Of course a backend-independent solution would be best.

Comment: Not really. I wrote my own helper function, but it works only in some backends. There are basically three problems: 1. finding out the screen size OS- and backend-independent 2. setting the window size backend-independent 3. setting the window position backend-independent. When I find some time, I'll try to test my function a bit better and will post it if I find a reasonably good solution.